# Matrix $A$ has two distinct real eigenvalues iff $k$ is greater than what?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> The matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}3&k\\8&8\end{bmatrix}$ has two distinct real eigenvalues **iff** $k > ?$

So I found the determinant by doing:

$(3 - \lambda)(8 - \lambda) - 8k = \lambda^2 - 11\lambda + 24 - 8k \implies \lambda = 8, \lambda = 3$ The thing is, I'm not really sure what they are asking me because I have found what the eigenvalues are: $\lambda_1 = 8, \lambda_2 = 3$.

I'm assuming I need to solve for $k$ somehow but it doesn't seem very straightforward to me, what am I missing here?

Comment: How did you get $\lambda=8$ and $\lambda=3$? The characteristic polynomial is in terms of $k$, so if you solve for $\lambda$, the results should also be in terms of $k$.

Comment: The eigenvalues you found are correct when $k = 0$, but not for different values of $k$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the characteristic equation of this matrix is given by
$$
\lambda^2 - 11\lambda + (24 - 8k) = 0
$$
The question is to find which values of $k$ produce two distinct real roots $\lambda$ to this equation.  It is helpful to consider the *discriminant* of this quadratic equation, namely
$$
b^2 - 4ac = 121 - 4(24 - 8k)
$$
recall that a quadratic equation will have distinct real roots iff its discriminant is positive.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that. So $121 - 96 +32k = 25 + 32k = 0 \implies 25 = -32k \implies k > -25/32$ Thanks so much @Om !

Comment: I will reward you points  because to me, this is the most straight foward explanation considering the *discriminant* of the quadratic equation. This is very useful

Comment: @Yusha Appreciate it, and glad you found this useful.

Answer (score 4):

The determinant is $$(3 - \lambda)(8 - \lambda) - 8k = \lambda^2 - 11\lambda + 24 - 8k.$$

In order to find the eigenvalues, you have to solve the equation $$\lambda^2 - 11\lambda + 24 - 8k = 0.$$

The solutions are:

$$\lambda = \frac{11 \pm \sqrt{11^2 - 4(24-8k)}}{2} = \frac{11 \pm \sqrt{25+32k}}{2}$$

which of course depend on $k$.

The two solutions are different and real if the part under square root is positive. That is:

$$25 +32 k > 0 \Rightarrow k > -\frac{25}{32}.$$

Answer (score 4):

$\lambda^2 - 11\lambda + 24 - 8k = 0\\
\lambda = \dfrac {11 \pm \sqrt{25 +32k}}{2} $

$A$ has 2 distinct real egeinvalues if
$25 +32k>0$

Answer (score 2):

You need to solve the equation with $\lambda$ the variable and $k$ a parameter.

The solutions are 
$$ -\frac{11}{2} \pm\sqrt{\frac{11^2}{4} - (24 - 8k)  } $$
These are the eigenvalues of the matrix in dependence of $k$.

These two are distinct and real  if and only if 
$$\frac{11^2}{4} - (24 - 8k)> 0.$$ 
Solve this to get your  $k$.